# Why did a nearly 2 year old answer suddenly get flagged as "Low Quality"?

Tags: discussion, review

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/56387/5517) from Oct '18 (nearly 2 years ago as of today, Sept 18, 2020) just showed up in the review queue as "Potentially low quality because of its **length** and **content**."

[image]

For 2 years, it's been just fine. Have there been system changes that are impacting how the system sees answers and it's being applied retroactively and not just to new content?

Granted, I asked a question about it when it was originally posted, and the OP never responded, but that doesn't mean it's low quality, it just needs a bit more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because another user flagged it as low quality, which feeds the review queues in order to get more pairs of eyes to review the answer.

If you agree that it is low quality you can action appropriately in the review queue, or you can skip reviewing it altogether.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had no idea. I'd always assumed that these warnings were system generated, but I see _actually reading the message, not reading what I ass-u-med was there_ that it just says "flagged", not "automatically flagged". #ReadingComprehensionFail

Comment: Nitpicking, but technically, it must have been a Not An Answer flag and not a (Very) Low Quality flag; see [my answer here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4140/8282) and the links therein.

Comment: @Glorfindel thank you for clarifying