# How do I flag as "low quality"?

Tags: support, flagging, review

In answer to [this question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/why-did-a-nearly-2-year-old-answer-suddenly-get-flagged-as-low-quality) about Low Quality flags, I was told that these flags are user generated, not system generated.

I took a look at the list of flags available (to me, at least), and I don't see one that jumps out at me as being the "put this in the low-quality review queue".

[image]

Which option do I select for something I believe should go into the "Low Quality" review queue?

Comment: which post have you tried to flag? if it has positive score you can't flag as low quality.

Comment: It was an answer, not a question, and I didn't note the vote count. I will have to see if I can find this one in particular to see what the voting was on it.

Comment: question or answer does not matter, that's why I said "post"

Answer (score 6):

An answer can only be flagged as Very Low Quality when it

- has a [score of 0 or lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208604/295232)
- is [less than 7 days old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635/4751173)

If the score is the problem, you can try to downvote it first, and open the dialog again. Flagging it as Not An Answer *will* put it in the Low Quality Posts review queue as well, but if it does attempt to answer the question it isn't really appropriate.

This also means the answer you mentioned in the [linked question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/why-did-a-nearly-2-year-old-answer-suddenly-get-flagged-as-low-quality) has been flagged as Not An Answer, not as Very Low Quality.

By the way, the system *does* generate Very Low Quality flags on posts which don't pass the quality filter, it just does that the moment the post is submitted, not two years later.

Comment: The flag reasons screen shot was not from the linked question, it was from a different question. I'll have to see if I can find this answer again and check the vote count to see if that's the issue. I'm pretty certain it just a few hours old when I grabbed that screen shot.